# Performance do COUNT(*) e COUNT(1)

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, desempenho, count

Qual é a diferença entre `COUNT(1)` e `COUNT(*)` em uma consulta SQL?

Por exemplo:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM USUARIOS;
```

e

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USUARIOS;
```

- Existe alguma diferença de interações dentro do SBGD?
- Qual seria mais rápido?
- Dependeria do SGBD que estou utilizando?

Comment: Tem quem diga que `count(1)` pode ser mais rápido no sql server, mas eu mesmo nunca vi isso de fato. Só sei que pondo `*` ou qualquer constante é mais rápido do que referenciando coluna

Comment: Nas versões recentes do Oracle "dá igual" , https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:1337911574066::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:1156159920245

Comment: Voce vai encontrar em alguns lugares que é a mesma coisa, mas eu gosto [dessa explicação.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2710703/2879341)

Comment: Pelo que explica [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1) não a diferença. O mesmo serve pro `exists`

Comment: Nos motores de SGBD mais recentes e mais comuns, não há diferença.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De que banco de dados está falando? Em que base de dados? Quando se fala de performance é difícil fazer asserções definitivas. Pode mudar de acordo com a implementação, então o SQL Server pode dar uma coisa e o PostgreSQL dar outra. Pode mudar de uma versão para outra, pode mudar de acordo com a configuração daquele banco ou do sistema todo. Pode variar de acordo com os dados armazenados. Performance depende de detalhe de implementação.

Se o otimizador do banco de dados achar que deve será exatamente o mesmo.

Note que a sintaxe aí é muito simples. Em *queries* mais complexas (`JOIN`) pode nem dar o resultado esperado quando se usa `COUNT(1)`. Fora isto o fato de ter uma constante no lugar de todos campos não irá diferir porque a contagem será feita em todas as linhas que passarem pelo filtro.

Tem uma [excelente resposta sobre isto no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2710703/221800).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

As consultas de Count(*) ou Count(coluna ou qualquer outra coisa), não tem diferença em niveis de performance, inclusive foi um dos assuntos abordados no blog do Gustavo Maia na categoria "Mitos do SQL Server", mais detalhes em:

http://gustavomaiaaguiar.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!F4F5C630410B9865!658.entry?sa=267685225

Mais em questão de boas práticas é aconselhável colocar o nome da coluna, desde que a coluna NOT NULL.

Answer (score 1):

A diferença é simples:

- COUNT(*) contará o número de registros.
- COUNT(nome_da_coluna) irá contar o número de registros não nulos.

Comment: Essa resposta visa atender a demanda dessa questão https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/247602/64969, porem do jeito que ficou redigida não responde a esta pergunta atual. Se você contextualizar dizendo que existe um outro `count`, deixando claro que tem informações relevantes em temas suficientemente próximos desta pergunta, então torna-se uma resposta válida

Answer (score 0):

Os dois selects **não tem diferença** no desempenho.

Nos dois casos, ele conta todos os valores da tabela, inclusive se as colunas estiverem nulas. Para contar as linhas o SQL varre a tabela inteira (Table Scan) e, em seguida, realiza as operações referentes ao COUNT (Stream Aggregate).