# Diferença entre usar COUNT em coluna e COUNT com "*"

Tags: sql

Realizei 2 `querys` em um banco onde precisava saber qual a quantidade de registros baseado em uma coluna porém se eu alterar o parametro de `COUNT()` os resultados são diferentes.

```
SELECT COUNT(`time`) as 'tempo' 
from db.table 
WHERE `time` <= 3000 
AND (`created_at` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW();
// A coluna `time` é do tipo "float" e armazena valores do tipo: 1.000, 0.985, 32.000

SELECT COUNT(*) as 'tempo' 
from db.table 
WHERE `time` <= 3000 
AND (`created_at` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW();
```

Qual é a entre usar com `*` e com o nome da coluna?

Comment: Acabei de fazer um teste aqui, e o `COUNT` só funciona diferente com campos de datas, se você fizer por exemplo `COUNT(2)`, vai funcionar corretamente, ou até se você colocar qualquer outro campo que não seja do tipo `datetime`, `time`, `date` ou `timestamp` ele vai funcionar.

Comment: @RobertodeCampos o campo `time` é do tipo `float`

Comment: Então campos do tipo `float` e seus derivados também não funciona. Os campos de data e hora também trabalham com ponto flutuante então talvez esteja ai o problema.

Comment: @Maniero acredito que não seja duplicada e não entendi a explicação do outro topico que voce marcou.

Comment: No tópico que está marcado como duplicado eu acabei de dar uma resposta que explica a diferença entre os dois comandos @RafaelAcioly

Comment: @DavidAlves ótima tentativa, mas ficou fora de contexto lá... vou sugerir algumas melhorias para a morada atual da resposta

Comment: @RafaelAcioly pode argumentar porque não? Se me convencer eu reabro.