# Select para trazer a quantidade de determinados registros em tabelas relacionadas

Tags: mysql, query, select

Fala galera, é o seguinte, no banco de dados MYSQL eu tenho essas 3 tabelas:

CONTROLES: Aqui eu faço as entradas de treinamentos realizados. Perceba que é possível inserir varios colaboradores na mesma linha

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

COLABORADORES:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

SETORES:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A coluna **colaboradores** da tabela CONTROLE é uma chave estrangeira da tabela COLABORADORES.
A coluna **setores** da tabela COLABORADORES é uma chave estrangeira da tabela SETORES.

Eu gostaria de um select que me trouxesse a quantidade de colaboradores por setor que participaram do treinamento.

Ficaria assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Amigo, tem certeza sobre essa "chave estrangeira" na tabela CONTROLES? Ao que me parece você está armazenando uma representação de um array em texto. Posso estar errado, mas isto não é uma FK, e não teria como você fazer esta consulta de maneira trivial com essa estrutura.

Comment: Sim, é um array, pois preciso inserir vários colaboradores na mesma linha. Esses registro são os IDs da tabela colaboradores. Funciona como uma FK, mas de fato não é. Quanto a consulta é possível sim, deve ter alguma maneira. Estou tentando com INNER JOIN, mas ainda não consegui.

Comment: Verifica se a resposta que sugeri resolve seu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode facilmente obter esse resultado utilizando `group by`, veja este exemplo:

```
Select s.nome, count(s.id) as quantidade from setores s, colaboradores c where s.id = c.SETOR Group by s.id
```

Veja o exemplo funcionando no [SQL Findle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87cb3a/7/0)

[Documentação sobre o Group BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Comment: lazyFox, achei incrível essa solução, me fez avançar bastante. Porém esse select está me trazendo todos os colaboradores e setores cadastrados. Eu tenho 15 setores e 256 colaboradores. Eu preciso que ele me traga apenas os que fizeram o curso, ou seja, apenas o input que foi feito na tabela CONTROLES.

Comment: Ou li mal a pergunta, ou então você fez alguma edição :) De qualquer modo vou deixar aqui a resposta que poderá vir a ser útil a outros utilizadores. Porém será melhor verificar as outras respostas pois vão mais de acordo com o que pretende.

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, como você provavelmente está utilizando o tipo de dados JSON devido ao conteúdo da coluna COLABORADORES na tabela CONTROLES. Você pode fazer desta forma.. (Note que não testei esse select, mas é esse o caminho)

```
SELECT 
setor.nome as setor,
count(colaborador.id) as quantidade
FROM SETORES setor
JOIN COLABORADORES colaborador 
    ON colaborador.setor = setor.id
JOIN CONTROLES controle 
    ON JSON_CONTAINS(controle.colaboradores, CAST(colaborador.id as CHAR))
GROUP BY setor.id
```

Já que você está trabalhando com JSON, vale olhar na documentação algumas funções uteis.

> [Functions That Search JSON Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

A solução mais completa e segura que encontrei foi a seguinte:

```
declare @aux_col varchar(255)
SELECT @aux_col = colaboradores FROM controles WHERE id = 1 --id do treinamento selecionado

-- esses três passos são necessários de acordo com os caracteres especiais mostrados no exemplo
select @aux_col = replace(@aux_col, '[', '')
select @aux_col = replace(@aux_col, ']', '')
select @aux_col = replace(@aux_col, '"', '')
-- esse passo é para facilitar a pesquisa, onde será sempre consultada a string ,codigo,
select @aux_col = ',' + @aux_col + ','

SELECT s.nome as setor, count(*) as quantidade
FROM colaboradores c
JOIN setores s on s.id = c.setor
WHERE LOCATE(',' + c.id + ',', @aux_col) > 0
GROUP BY s.nome
ORDER BY s.nome
```

A validação no `locate` usando vírgula antes e depois do `id` é necessária porque se não existisse, a pesquisa pelo código `1` retornaria verdade se existisse o código `11`, por exemplo.

Comment: Note que ele pediu a quantidade de servidores, agrupado por setor, que participaram de um treinamento. Isto exige a relação com a tabela CONTROLE. A sua query retorna apenas a quantidade de funcionários por setor.

Comment: putz, tens razão. Me ative as duas últimas tabelas.. vou arrumar a resposta. Obrigado, @IsraelMerljak

Comment: Cara, nunca use um count(*), isso acaba pesando na consulta em um banco muito populado. Sempre especifique um campo no count...

Comment: Na real, no quesito _performance_ não tem diferença entre uma ou outra abordagem (ex: [esse tratamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/214077/performance-do-count-e-count1)), o fato de contar entre `*`, `campo` ou `1` (por exemplo) pesaria na contagem de valores nulos, que neste caso não diferenciaria. (@VictorLaio, se eu falei besteira, me corrija =p )

Comment: Isso pode variar demais de banco pra banco, porque são n fatores que vão influenciar. Na minha experiencia onde trabalhei teve casos em que houve um pequeno ganho de performance fazendo a modificação. Mas caso queira saber mais recomendo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710621/count-vs-count1-vs-countpk-which-is-better/2710703#2710703