# Dúvida para contar registros em uma consulta do banco de dados MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, operador-like

Em um banco de dados MySQL, eu tenho duas colunas do tipo varchar que me traz registros nesse formato:

```
["165","184","192","209","242"]
```

Mais um exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cada número entre aspas duplas é um registro, ou seja, é o ID de algum aluno.

Eu preciso de um select que me traga quantos IDs tem por coluna.

No caso da coluna `curso1`, o resultado seria `8`.

É possível realizar esse tipo de consulta?

Comment: dá uma sacada [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/330023/select-para-trazer-a-quantidade-de-determinados-registros-em-tabelas-relacionada/330025#330025), acredito que é um problema parecido

Comment: Bom  vejo  aqui  um problema,  um você não está fazendo o armazenamento de forma mais eficiente, pelo que percebi você precisaria de uma  tabela de relação  N:N isso facilitaria sua vida para obter dados.

Comment: Qual a versão do Mysql vc está usando?

Comment: @AlvaroAlves, Versão do servidor: 10.1.26-MariaDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução para seu problema:

Fiz um banco de testes ao qual adicionei os registros e fiz um teste, abaixo segue o que você precisa:

```
SELECT
  curso1,
  CASE WHEN COALESCE(curso1, '"')='"' THEN 0
  ELSE
    length(curso1)-length(replace(curso1, ',', ''))+
    (length(curso1)-length(replace(curso1, ' and ', ''))) DIV 5
    +1
  END
FROM
  suaTabela
```

altere o "suaTabela" pelo nome da tabela e faça a consulta, tentei realizar este procedimento via REGEX mas ele só retorna 1 ou 0.

Segue imagem ilustrativa:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: uuaaull, incrível.  Excelente solução. Me fez avançar bastante. Mas no caso do seu exemplo, para o que eu preciso, ele teria que retornar 11.  Estou tentando com o operador SUM usando a query que você fez.