# COUNT(*) x COUNT(1) x COUNT(id)

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, desempenho, count

Gostaria de entender melhor sobre a diferença entre essas formas de usar o contador:

```
select COUNT(*) from tabela

select COUNT(1) from tabela

select COUNT(id) from tabela
```

[Esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/214077/performance-do-count-e-count1) trata da performance entre duas das formas, mas gostaria de detalhar melhor o que difere cada uma, além de adicionar à questão uma terceira maneira.

- Existe diferença (real) de performance?
- Pode existir diferença nos resultados?
- É possível mapear o melhor uso para cada uma das formas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> select COUNT(*) from tabela
> ```

Pega todas as colunas da tabela durante a consulta, aí todos os dados estarão disponíveis na memória para o SGDB fazer a operação de contagem e outras coisas. Se não houver otimização. Mas muitos DBs otimizam isto de alguma forma para uma expressão simples assim, alguns podem fazer isto até mesmo em tempo constante O(1). Caso contrário será O(n).

> ```
> select COUNT(1) from tabela
> ```

Pega uma constante, ou seja, um valor que já está na memória, portanto, em tese é para ser absurdamente mais rápido por nem ter que carregar nada do banco de dados, mas depende de ter alguma otimização. Sempre depende da implementação do banco de dados. Ele pode ser O(1), mas ma maioria será O(n) mesmo. A diferença é que a carga de cada uma dos elementos será potencialmente menor.

> ```
> select COUNT(id) from tabela
> ```

Aqui lê apenas uma coluna, costuma ser mais rápido que o primeiro (alguns casos de tabelas com poucas e curtas colunas pode ser igual), e será igual ao anterior por ter que ler todas as linhas, mesmo que não traga nada além do indicador para o contador, mas novamente, a não ser que tenha alguma otimização, neste caso este pode ser bem mais lento que o anterior, mas pode não ser. Ele pode ser O(n) ou O(1).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/Count.sql).

## Mais detalhes

Alguns bancos de dados possuem uma otimização onde a contagem total sem filtro (sem `WHERE`) já tenha armazenado automaticamente e é garantido que sempre está atualizado, é neste caso onde a complexidade será O(1). Os DBs mais escaláveis não costumam ter isto por dificuldades técnicas. Posso citar o exemplo do MyISAM do MySQL que sempre sabe o `COUNT()` sem filtro ou outros critérios sendo usados. Mas na maioria dos casos será O(n). Se tiver `WHERE` ou outras informações no `SELECT` ou faça um `JOIN` ou tenha outras características que pode afetar a contagem certamente será O(n).

Se for O(n) a diferença de performance será pequena, especialmente em tabelas com linhas muito curtas. Porque ele terá que contar mesmo, terá que carregar todas as linhas para contar. Em linhas muito grandes pode haver diferença quando usa o `COUNT(*)`, mas só nestes casos. E aí os outros 2 exemplos devem ser iguais, porque ler a linha só para contar sem precisar usar informação alguma e ler um simples `id` dá na mesma.

Para entender isso tudo depende de entender como funciona o armazenamento interno do *engine* responsável por isso no seu SGDB e também como funciona a *file system* de forma geral. E entender que cada página que o software faz bater no disco (ou SSD ou outras forma de armazenamento) é absurdamente mais lento (chega ser 3 ordens de magnitude) que pegar um dado que já está na memória, não importa o tamanho do dado, embora mude um tiquinho a proporção em alguns casos. E aí entender quando precisa ir no armazenamento secundário ou não. Por isso o cache pode fazer uma diferença absurda, em alguns casos extremos pode ir de menos de 1 milissegundo quando tudo está em cache, para mais de 1 segundo quando nada está em cache.

> Existe diferença (real) de performance?

Depende um pouco de implementação se é um problema de performance ou não, porque é possível otimizar sabendo que na prática, este exemplo, não faz diferença, afinal a carga dos dados tem zero função nesta consulta específica. Deixar de carregar mesmo dizendo para fazê-lo não muda nada. Aí só testando em cada caso para saber se o faz ou não. E o teste poderá mudar em cada execução. Ao contrário do que as pessoas imaginam testar performance de banco de dados é muito complicado. As pessoas esperam respostas lineares, mas em algo que tem tantas otimizações isto não acontece.

> Pode existir diferença nos resultados?

Não deveria neste caso na maioria dos DBs, em outros casos pode.

> É possível mapear o melhor uso para cada uma das formas?

Acredito que sim, seja lá o que isso quer dizer. Mas o básico é testar cada um onde vai usar e ver qual é mais rápido (fazendo em vários cenários, considerando o cache). Em outros exemplos pode ser mais uma questão de fazer o que espera ou não, mas só dá para analisar caso a caso.

Comment: E o `SELECT SUM(1)`? Como ficaria em relação aos outros? Em relação a performance.

Comment: @JoãoPedroSchmitz é para ser instantâneo porque está fazendo nada no DB, mas novamente depende de otimização, o que não duvido que deixe de existir em algum DB.